# Which Version of maven supports exclusion from dependency Management

Tags: maven, maven-3, dependency-management

I have a dependency inherited from one external project dependency,  which we don't have control and we want to exclude a specific dependency from that project. Tried several exclusion attempts but still not able to exclude the same.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>..</groupId>
<artifactId>...</artifactId>
<version>...</version>
<type>pom</type>
<scope>import</scope>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Could anyone let me know is it possible to exclude the dpendency. I am using 3.5.2 maven version.

Comment: Using Maven 3.5.4 the exclusions are working fine. Usually, I set them in dependencyManagement section as you mentioned.

Comment: Your dependency seems strange because you have type pom and scope import. Why?

Comment: @KérdezösködőIndián tried the latest version 3.6.0 but did not solve my issue.

Comment: Exclusions work in all newer Maven versions ... there must be some error in your pom. Could you add more details, and especially answer my question on why you want an exclusion on an import scoped dependency?

Comment: @JFMeier  this project from where i want to exclude a dependency is managed by some other team and we cannot ask them to update the dependency of a specific jar that is coming as a part of existing imports which is done few years back. So i want to exclude that dependency and add my version of dependency .But the problem is as it is managed through `<scope>import</scope>` , even if we add exclusions, and add our dependency with a correct version ,it overrides the version.Hope i answered your question.this a case of transitive dependency Refer this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5600

Comment: You can still do the exclusion by adding a dependencyManagement entry for the specific dependency, so if you want to exclude the dependency B of A, add a dependencyManagement entry for A which excludes B. You do not need to do it for the imported BOM.

Comment: Furthermore, if you want the dependency, but just want a different version, just add a dependencyManagement entry for the dependency with your desired version. No need to write exclusions then.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that version is not released yet, but there is a workaround.

There is an example of dependencies import at [Importing Dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies) with following explanation:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>Z</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Z</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>X</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>Y</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

> In the example above Z imports the managed dependencies from both X and Y. However, both X and Y contain dependency a. Here, version 1.1 of a would be used since X is declared first and a is not declared in Z's dependencyManagement.

Given that description, you should be able to **override** the version and/or scope of offending dependency if you define it **BEFORE** imports.

Following the same example, the definition below should use version 2.0 of `a`:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>Z</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Z</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>test</groupId>
                <artifactId>a</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>X</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>Y</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Make sure to check the effective pom!

Answer (score 1):

Exclusions have been available for a long time in Maven, that's not the problem. Keep you current Maven version, it will do it's job well.

I think there is a confusion there.
From the pom excerpt you wrote above, we can see that you import a pom (scope "import") which is often called a BOM (for Bill Of Material).

A BOM is imported in a `<dependencyManagement>` section (not showed above) and it's goal can be summed up by: "I define many different libraries, including their versions so that if you import me you can ommit to specify the version of the libraries you define, but you still have to explicitly define your direct dependencies".

By that, I mean that a BOM does not "force" you to use the libraries it defines: it only hints that in the case that you or your dependencies depends upon a specific library Z, then the version of Z will be forced to the one defined in the BOM".

**So the BOM does not "forces" dependencies upon you so you cannot "exclude" any dependency where the BOM is defined.**
You have to find exactly where the dependency Z you want to exclude is defined in your **own** project and remove it there. It may also be brought as a transitive dependency in which case you have to use exclude it from the dependency you have specified using the `<exclusions>` / `<exclusion>` tags and the `groupId` / `artifactId`.

In conclusion: change your approach, you're not looking in the right place. And also use Maven dependency plugin which is your best friend to understand where your unwanted dependency comes from exactly ( `mvn dependency:tree` ).

I hope it helps

PS: you did not tell but do you have a multimodule project ?